# Do-while loop with if-statement in body which only prints a message after one iteration?

Tags: c++

This probably requires only basic problem solving skills but I am trying to create a very short way to: ask the user for input and only say that the input is not legit after it did not pass the condition check at least once. A do while loop seemed to fit..

How I implemented it below will always create a problem in that 1 specific number creates a bug, namely if the user enters 0 you don't get the message while you should, I could change it to a very special number but still this front-end bug would remain. I come from a Java background in which null is the default value making this easy, but because of efficiency reasons this seems not to be the case in c++. I could declare a `bool` but that seems like too much of a workaround.

Here is the code I have now:

```
int birthYear = 0;
do {
    if (birthYear != 0) cout << "Your input " << birthYear << " is not a legit birthday";
    cout << "What is the year you were born?: "; cin >> birthYear;
} while (birthYear < 1900 || birthYear > 2100);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic example where neither the `while` nor the `do`/`while` loop is an exact fit, because you need to do something before and after checking the loop condition.

Rewrite your loop as a "forever" loop with a `break` in the middle:

```
for (;;) {
    cout << "What is the year you were born?: ";
    cin >> birthYear;
    if (birthYear >= 1900 && birthYear <= 2100) {
        break;
    }
    cout << "Your input " << birthYear << " is not a legit birthday";
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` would work too. if the topic starter insists on using `while` loop ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a flag:

```
int birthYear = 0;
bool birthYearInvalid = false;
do {
    if (birthYearInvalid) cout << "Your input " << birthYear << " is not a legit birthday";
    cout << "What is the year you were born?: "; cin >> birthYear;
    birthYearInvalid = (birthYear < 1900 || birthYear > 2100);
} while (birthYearInvalid);
```

One extra variable.. could be good (more self documentation)